# %%G from For Loop changing from index to %G using

Tags: matlab, batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to write a batch file to automate some routine Matlab processes. The batch file loops through from 0 to a set value (usually between 50 and 75) using the For /L structure. The script copies the main Matlab script to the subfolder and runs it. The batch would normally continue onward so I put a :loop to wait until the Matlab ends.

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM The format is matlab_auto.in (max value). 
For /L %%G in (0,1,%1) do (
REM Sanity check
echo 1 %%G

REM Create Outputs folder if non-existent
if not exist Outputs md Outputs

REM Copy .m file into deg folder and cd to folder
copy values_calc.m %%Gsort\values_calc.m
cd %%Gsort
echo Got to folder

    REM Running .m script and sanity check
echo 2 %%G
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -logfile output.log -r "run('values_calc.m');"
echo 3 %%G

REM Waiting for matlab to finish
:loop
tasklist /fi "imagename eq MATLAB.exe" |find ":" > nul
echo 4 %%G
if errorlevel 1 goto loop
echo Finished Matlab  
echo 5 %%G

REM Copy .m outputs into outputs folder, ignoring confirmation
copy Output_*.* ..\Outputs /Y
echo Copied outputs 

REM Sanity check and return home
echo 6 %%G
cd %~dp0
echo Home again
```

)

The problem I'm having is that when it ends after the first iteration of the For loop. Echo 1, 2, 3 are 0. Echo 4 shows 0 the first time through :loop but then it shows %G for the remainder of the loops and at Echos 5 and 6. It also does not continue into further iterations of the For loop. I'm assuming this is because %%G is no longer a number (or in the range specified).

I have tried implementing a call subroutine to use the goto outside the loop but then it opens the Matlab dozens of times, crashing the computer.

Any insight or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Changed the :: for commenting to REM. It did not resolve this issue but looks better.

EDIT 2: I have a test case that demonstrates the problem. Its something with the :loop or goto. 
    echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

```
for /l %%G in (0,1,5) do (
    :loop
    echo %%G
    pause
    if %%G==0 goto loop
)
```

Comment: Off the top of my head and without actually trying anything, I know that `for` loops absolutely _hate_ `::` as comments. Try replacing them with `REM` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The execution of a GOTO command *cancel* any active (pending) FOR or IF commands that may be nested inside parentheses at any level. This way, the commands placed below the `:loop` label are executed inside the FOR context *the first time*, but after the `goto` command they are executed as if they were placed outside the FOR loop! The way to solve this problem is extracting the code below the label into a subroutine and then `call :loop` in the FOR.

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM The format is matlab_auto.in (max value). 
For /L %%G in (0,1,%1) do (
   REM Sanity check
   echo 1 %%G

   REM Create Outputs folder if non-existent
   if not exist Outputs md Outputs

   REM Copy .m file into deg folder and cd to folder
   copy values_calc.m %%Gsort\values_calc.m
   cd %%Gsort
   echo Got to folder

   REM Running .m script and sanity check
   echo 2 %%G
   matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -logfile output.log -r "run('values_calc.m');"
   echo 3 %%G

   REM Waiting for matlab to finish
   call :loop
   echo Finished Matlab  
   echo 5 %%G

   REM Copy .m outputs into outputs folder, ignoring confirmation
   copy Output_*.* ..\Outputs /Y
   echo Copied outputs 

   REM Sanity check and return home
   echo 6 %%G
   cd %~dp0
   echo Home again

)
goto :EOF

:loop
tasklist /fi "imagename eq MATLAB.exe" |find ":" > nul
REM echo 4 %%G
if errorlevel 1 goto loop
exit /B
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. When I was trying to use a subroutine earlier I did not have exit /B or the goto :EOF. Thank you.